# How to block javascript:// as url parameter

Tags: php, javascript, xss

I'm  currently writing a PHP script for a guestbook in PHP where people can put their name, website and messages in a form, but I want to prevent someone from putting javascript:// in de url box to reduce the risk of XSS, I've tried to solve this with:

```
<?php filter_var($_POST['website'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ?>
```

But I'm still able of putting javascript:// in de url box how could I prevent this?

Comment: Because that is a valid url. You'd have to parse the url and check what protocol is being used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

with preg_replace

```
$website = preg_replace("/(javascript:\/\/)/i", "http://", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['website']));
```

or with str_ireplace

```
$website = str_ireplace("javascript:", "http:", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['website']));
```

Comment: If $Website is put into a <a href=""></a> your replacing is circumvented if you html encode any of the letters in javascript.

java&#115;cript:alert(1)

Answer (score 3):

A clean solution would be using PHP's [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and to check if the used protocol is HTTP or in a list of allowed protocols if you're allowing http:// and skype:// for example…

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
$tmp = parse_url($url);

if ($tmp['scheme'] === 'http') {
  echo 'is http://';
}

if (in_array($tmp['scheme'], array('http', 'skype', 'call')) {
  echo 'is allowed protocol';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$chk = parse_url($url);

switch ($chk['scheme']) {
case 'http':
case 'https':
    break;
default:
    // throw error here
    break;
}
```